# Having trouble getting full 2560x1440 resolution output from a Mac Book Pro

Tags: macos, display, macbook-pro, external-display

I just got a Dell U2713hm to hook up to my Mac Book Pro. I thought it was a 2560x1440 monitor but I'm only getting 2048x1152.

I'm using the mini display port to VGA, am I just stuck with the lower resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a limitation of your adapter. Many cards have a 400MHz DAC for the VGA output which only gets up to 2048x1536 or so. Try a dual-link DVI cable? (Single-link DVI or HDMI won't get much above 1920x1080 so you will need a dual-link cable.)

Edit: it you're using Apple's official adapter, it should go up to 2048x1536. That will still only get you about 3 million pixels per frame. If you want 2560x1440 you need something that can handle 3.6 million pixels.

Comment: I have the dual-link DVI adapter by apple (http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter) and a DIV-D (24+1) cable. For some reason the image is blurry on a high resolution (in Mac's display settings it shows 2560x1440, but on the Dell menu it shows 1280x1440). Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Apple Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter only goes to 1920x1200. From [Apple Mini DisplayPort adapters: Frequently asked questions (FAQ)](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204149): **2. What is the maximum resolution available for use with the Apple Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter?** *The resolution available with the Apple Mini DisplayPort to VGA Adapter is 1920 x 1200. VGA displays that use higher refresh rates (such as 85 Hz) at resolutions of 1600 x 1200 or greater may not generate video properly until you lower the refresh rate.* To be clear: That's not VGA's fault. ;^)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is definitely the mini display port to VGA adapter.

I have achieved 2560x1440 with the Dell U2711 and a Macbook Pro by using a [DisplayPort to DisplayPort-Mini cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0034X6SCY).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was this.

I bought a Thunderbolt/Mini Displayport to Displayport cable v1.2 (4k compatible)
I also used the http://embdev.net/topic/284710 but i'm not sure it was even necessary
in my situation.
I'm on the latest Sierra 10.12.3 so maybe it is fixed now.
But everything looks fine now on my Dell U2723HM and Macbook Pro 15" Retina.
Hope this helps. I was also in the same situation as everybody else with only Full HD
resolution but now i have 2560x1440 and it looks great.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I attached a new BenQ SW2700PT external monitor to my MacBook Pro 13" (Late 2012). I could not get a resolution > 1920x1080 using a DVI adaptor on the MacBook mini display port connected to HDMI on the monitor. With a HDMI to HDMI the max available was 1080p. However a mini-Dispaly Port (MacBook) to Display Port (on Monitor) cable gave me 2048 x 1152, with a max of 2560 x 1440 resolution.

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Answers that say, "me too!" are aggressively deleted, since they're a common mistake by new users. It looks like you have a partial answer at the end, and you might want to reword it to make that clearer, perhaps moving the solution to the top?